# OpenCV_ Problem in Saving cropped Image Into a Seperate Directory

Tags: python, opencv, error-handling

I am trying to crop many images from one folder and save the cropped one in a seperate folder. All codes ran well except the last block when I am trying to save it with `cv2.imwrite`. I receive indentation error however I checked it and doesn't seem to be the case here. Thanks in advance.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from os import listdir
import cv2
```

```
directory = "/home/masoud/masoud/crop/obj"
destination = "/home/masoud/masoud/crop/cropped-images"

for file in os.listdir(directory): 
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, file), 'r') as f:
        
            for line in f:  # changed to file handle
                line = line.rstrip() # remove trailing '\n'
                nums = line.split()
                four_nums = nums[1:5]  
                # print(four_nums)
        image_address_wo_format = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(directory, file))[0]
        print(image_address_wo_format)
```

```
image_address = image_address_wo_format + '.jpg'
        
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(directory, image_address))
        print(img)
```

```
width, height, channels = img.shape 
        print(width, height, channels)
```

```
left = width * (float(nums[1]) - float(nums[3]) / 2)
        top = height * (float(nums[2]) - float(nums[4]) / 2)
        right = width * (float(nums[1]) + float(nums[3]) / 2)
        bottom = height * (float(nums[2]) + float(nums[4]) / 2)
        print(left, top, right, bottom)
```

```
im_cropped = img[int(top): int(bottom-top), int(left):int(right-left)]
        print(im_cropped)
```

```
cropped_image_address = destination + "/.cropped"+ ".jpg"
        print(cropped_image_address)
```

```
cv2.imwrite(cropped_image_address, im_cropped)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    else:
        continue
```

ERROR:

```
 File "<ipython-input-76-f4779e4590eb>", line 3
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: You likely have indented the if with space (or alternately tabs), but used the opposite for the else: